# What is the difference between rowsum and rowSums in R?

Tags: r

I note that R has both of these functions: `rowsum` and `rowSums`.

However, R only has `colSums`, but not `colsum`.

Then, what is the difference between `rowsum` and `rowSums`?

Comment: One way to improve this question might be to include the description from each function's documentation describing what they do, and then identify what it is you find confusing about those two descriptions.

Comment: I feel it's a valid question, don't know why it has been closed. Thanks @Benjamin for his answer to clear my confusion. A quick answer to PO is "rowsum" is actually calculating column sum of grouped data instead of row sum. It's a very bad function name.

Answer (score 5):

> Then, what is the difference between `rowsum` and `rowSums`?

From `help("rowsum")`

> Compute **column sums** across rows of a numeric matrix-like object for **each level** of a grouping variable.

with my highlights. And here is `help("rowSums")`

> Form row [...] sums and means for numeric arrays (or data frames).

So the latter gives a vector which length is the number of rows and the former gives you a [number of group] x [number of rows] output. Here are two examples

```r
n           <- 5L
n_groups    <- 3L
n_per_group <- 4L
n_rows      <- n_groups * n_per_group

# group variable
grp <- gl(n_groups, n_per_group, labels = letters[1:n_groups])

# data matrix
set.seed(67620866)
x <- matrix(signif(runif(n_rows * n), 2), n_rows)

# sum over groups for each column
rowsum(x, grp)
#R     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5]
#R a 1.9200 1.120 2.209 1.86 1.98
#R b 2.2443 1.730 1.800 2.43 1.86
#R c 2.9900 1.742 2.270 2.58 2.78
sum(x[grp == "a", 1]) # first entry
#R [1] 1.92

# sum over rows
rowSums(x)
#R  [1] 1.7190 2.8400 1.9200 2.6100 2.4300 2.7800 2.4000 2.4543 2.6800
#R [10] 3.9200 3.7440 2.0180
sum(x[1, ]) # first entry
#R [1] 1.719
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting "Compute **column sums** across..." in "help(rowsum)" documentation. It immediately solves my confusion about the output of rowsum function. I feel the function name of "rowsum" is super misleading. It should be much better to be called "colsum" instead.

Comment: “Column sums” is also a bad description because it does nothing to help the user know if that is a sum within or across columns.